# how to install a working haskell compiler on OSX?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I have downloaded the haskell platform 2013.2.O.O 64 bit and installed it according to the guide on a OSX version 10.9.2 (where i used Xcode to install the gcc compiler). I get the ghci to work, but when i try to compile hello.hs (containing: main = putStrLn "Hello, World!") I get a lot of errors and missing files (for instance math.h, stint.h). I appreciate any help of what I have done wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Xcode 5.  There is a known compatibility issue between Xcode5 and GHC 7.6.  See [the Haskell Platform MacOS X page](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) for a wrapper script that works around the issue.

Comment: thank you. I actually thought I had the most recent version of Xcode, but found out that I did not. I updated my Xcode, and ran the ghc-clang script as specified in your link. Afterwards I installed the haskell platform and could compile and run a simple hello world in haskell.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly help with the path you've chosen so far, but if you've got homebrew...

```
brew install ghc haskell-platform
```

Current versions from brew are ghc 7.6.3 and platform 2013.2.0.0

Comment: Thank you but that did not work for me. I went through the steps with brew with same results - is it some uninstall I should try first?

Comment: brew does not work very well with ghc and the haskell-platform in general. It's a real shame, considering how useful it is for other packages.

Comment: besides finally getting it to work in MacOSX. I also got it to work within a ubuntu-environment 13.10 64 bits (virtual box). I see that others have experienced problems with the sudo apt-get install haskell-platform - but I did not.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm not as much a power-user (haskell is not my day job), but for the mileage I need the brew package worked.

Comment: To your question, yes I imagine another install (source or otherwise) could conflict with the brew install. Whether or not brew's package is better you definitely want to try each at a time on its own.